# Why does iTerm2 / oh-my-zsh starts with an error? Where should I start looking?

Tags: zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

Question edit: **What are the places I should look to try to debug this?**

I use **iTerm2** with **oh-my-zsh**. At the beginning it worked perfectly, but since few weeks it starts with an error. Note the `↑1`:

```sh
Last login: Mon Sep 30 21:04:35 on ttys000
↑1 ~ →
```

Here is the screenshot :
[image: Error highlighted]

**Do you have any idea why that happens or how could I look for the cause?**

Note. I have *the same* setup at work, but that issue never occurred. I must have done something wrong on my personal machine and I am unable to see the cause.

Comment: No one knows what happened without any configuration provided.

Comment: That's my problem too: what configuration do I have to look for? I hope for an answer from someone who has already had the the same problem and to present his/her solution. :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but as a suggestion: folks are probably downvoting because the question is too specific (no one else knows what particular configuration you have on your machine). I think orienting the question more around "what are the places I should look to try to debug this" would be a good question and fits well with your answer.

Comment: I thought that my **how could I look for the cause?** is similar with your **what are the places I should look to try to debug this**. Obviously not. Thank you, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the problem. It was in **`~/.zshrc`**. At the end of the file there were 3 *serverless* commands:

```sh
113 # tabtab source for serverless package
114 # uninstall by removing these lines or running `tabtab uninstall serverless`
115 [[ -f /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/tabtab/.completions/serverless.zsh ]] && . /usr/local/lib    /node_modules/serverless/node_modules/tabtab/.completions/serverless.zsh
116 # tabtab source for sls package
117 # uninstall by removing these lines or running `tabtab uninstall sls`
118 [[ -f /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/tabtab/.completions/sls.zsh ]] && . /usr/local/lib/node_m    odules/serverless/node_modules/tabtab/.completions/sls.zsh
119
120 # tabtab source for slss package
121 # uninstall by removing these lines or running `tabtab uninstall slss`
122 [[ -f /Users/costin/node_modules/tabtab/.completions/slss.zsh ]] && . /Users/costin/node_modules/tabtab/.completion    s/slss.zsh
```

All these three commands fail with exit code `1`. By commenting them the error disappears.

As an answer I was expecting to be oriented to look for failing commands in `~/.zshrc` and maybe some other similar files.